# Cannot access GoogleApi

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, location

I'm try  to get location update but I get error :
error: cannot access GoogleApi
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,

this is my code

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("LocationUpLifeManager Thread");
mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest,
                mLocationCallback,
                mHandlerThread.getLooper());
```

Please help me thank.

Comment: Please provide some more bit of your code

Comment: I think there isn't problem in my code. I can run the source code in my laptop.but when i use computer i cannot build project... I think it's relate to sdk package

Comment: Is your Api Key correct and enabled ?

Comment: cannot access GoogleApi
class file for com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApi not found

Comment: Then, please update your plugins and android studio to the latest version.

Comment: Also, update the Gradle plugin

Comment: This should solve the problem

Comment: I changed distributionUrl to https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip and now work fine thank you

Comment: Good to know that your problem is solved